# how to convert this varchar to datetime2(7) format?

Tags: sql-server

Can any one help how to convert '20200309150920' string to Datetime like 2020-03-09 15:09:20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it within a table as follows:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    the_pk,
    CAST
    (
      CONCAT
      (
        SUBSTRING(str, 1, 4),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING(str, 5, 2),
        '-',
        SUBSTRING(str, 7, 2),
        ' ',
        SUBSTRING(str, 9, 2),
        ':',
        SUBSTRING(str, 11, 2),
        ':',
        SUBSTRING(str, 13, 2)
      ) AS DATETIME
    ) AS my_dat
  FROM test t
)
UPDATE test
  SET test.dat = cte.my_dat
FROM 
  test
INNER JOIN
  cte
  ON
    test.the_pk = cte.the_pk;
```

SQL Server has tricky `UPDATE` from a `SELECT` syntax - at least as far as I'm concerned! It's a bit verbose, I know, but I find that indenting helps clarity and maintenance down the road!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but you can do this by concatenating it into the proper form.

```
DECLARE @TimeString char(20) = '20200309150920'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7), 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(@TimeString,1,8)
       , ' '
       , SUBSTRING(@TimeString,9,2)
       , ':'
       , SUBSTRING(@TimeString,11,2)
       , ':'
       , SUBSTRING(@TimeString,13,2)
        )
    )
```